# Import highchart boost module via webpack

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to load the boost module after Highcharts is loaded. Is this correct?

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts');
require('highcharts/modules/boost')(Highcharts);
```

Using boost for path-to-canvas-image rendering.

http://www.highcharts.com/news/175-highcharts-performance-boost

I don't see any changes to the chart. Any ideas?

Comment: How many points do you have on your chart? Have you seen this npm module? https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-boost

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @DigantCKasundra yes, I did solve the problem. The amount of points determines if the chart is rendered with svg/canvas. Example helped: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/boost/area/

Comment: @DavidB thanks.  That's too bad b/c I had a page with many charts on it so each individual one was below the threshold but with the entire page, it really should have used Canvas.  I've since just written my own library.